# There's an error in your program: expected an indented block when I run this code

Tags: python

```
"""
Unit tests for google places.

@author: sam@slimkrazy.com
"""

from random import randint
import unittest
import warnings

from googleplaces import GooglePlaces,GooglePlacesSearchResult,GoogleAutocompleteSearchResult
from testfixtures import PLACES_QUERY_RESPONSE, AUTOCOMPLETE_QUERY_RESPONSE

DUMMY_API_KEY = 'foobarbaz'

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self._places_instance = GooglePlaces(DUMMY_API_KEY)

    def tearDown(self):
        self._places_instance = None

    def setUp(self):
    self._places_instance = GooglePlaces(DUMMY_API_KEY)

def tearDown(self):
    self._places_instance = None

def testSuccessfulPlaceResponse(self):
    query_result = GooglePlacesSearchResult(
            self._places_instance,
            PLACES_QUERY_RESPONSE)

    self.assertEqual(5, len(query_result.places), 'Place count is incorrect.')
    place_index = randint(0, len(query_result.places)-1)
    place = query_result.places[place_index]
    response_place_entity = PLACES_QUERY_RESPONSE['results'][place_index]

    # make sure Place.id and Place.reference raise appropriate warnings
    with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
        place_id = place.id
        place_reference = place.reference
        self.assertEqual(len(w), 2)
        self.assertEqual(w[0].category, FutureWarning)
        self.assertEqual(w[1].category, FutureWarning)

    self.assertEqual(place_id, response_place_entity.get('id'), 'ID value is incorrect.')
    self.assertEqual(place_reference,
                     response_place_entity.get('reference'),
                     'Reference value is incorrect.')
    self.assertEqual(place.name, response_place_entity.get('name'),
                     'Name value is incorrect.')
    self.assertEqual(place.vicinity, response_place_entity.get('vicinity'),
                     'Vicinity value is incorrect.')
    self.assertEqual(
            place.geo_location,
            response_place_entity['geometry']['location'],
            'Geo-location value is incorrect.')

def testSuccessfulAutocompleteResponse(self):
    query_result = GoogleAutocompleteSearchResult(
            self._places_instance,
            AUTOCOMPLETE_QUERY_RESPONSE)

    self.assertEqual(5, len(query_result.predictions), 'Prediction count is incorrect.')
    prediction_index = randint(0, len(query_result.predictions)-1)
    prediction = query_result.predictions[prediction_index]
    response_prediction_entity = AUTOCOMPLETE_QUERY_RESPONSE['predictions'][prediction_index]
    self.assertEqual(prediction.id, response_prediction_entity.get('id'), 'ID value is incorrect.')
    self.assertEqual(
                     prediction.place_id,
                     response_prediction_entity.get('place_id'),
                     'Place ID value is incorrect.')
    self.assertEqual(
                     prediction.reference,
                     response_prediction_entity.get('reference'),
                     'Reference value is incorrect.')
    self.assertEqual(prediction.description,
                     response_prediction_entity.get('description'),
                     'Description value is incorrect.')
    self.assertEqual(prediction.types,
                     response_prediction_entity.get('types'),
                     'Types value is incorrect.')
```

**This will appear :
There's an error in your program: expected an indented block**

Comment: It's exactly what it says: you failed to indent your function code at the given line, function SetUp.  When you post here, we *do* expect you to include the entire error message.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you failed to indent this part right here:

```
def setUp(self):
self._places_instance = GooglePlaces(DUMMY_API_KEY)
```

This should be the following instead:

```
def setUp(self):
    self._places_instance = GooglePlaces(DUMMY_API_KEY)
```

Answer (score -1):

Line # 25 had indentation error.

Change:

```
def setUp(self):
self._places_instance = GooglePlaces(DUMMY_API_KEY)
```

To:

```
def setUp(self):
    self._places_instance = GooglePlaces(DUMMY_API_KEY)
```